# Can you make notification pops up without refreshing the page?

Tags: laravel, notifications

Hi everyone I have a problem that my notification with Laravel Notify (https://github.com/mckenziearts/laravel-notify) only appears when I refreshed the page, here's how I used it:

I made a button with a link(a) that when clicked will route to a controller and inside the controller I call the notify like this:

```
notify()->success('test notification');
```

after that I return back the view

What I want is after we delete the data in controller, I want to show the notification in the view without reloading the page, is there any way to do that?

nb: I'm new ini laravel :D

Comment: use ajax and setInterval to check if there is new notification for user. or look into pusher with laravel for a better resolution

Comment: Look into https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting.

Comment: @Sumitkumar tried to use ajax and it works, thanks! :D. The workaround is to use javascript notification library instead of laravel's

Answer (score 1):

You should use broadcasting, so you can easily reflect server changes on client side. Look at this:

> In many modern web applications, WebSockets are used to implement realtime, live-updating user interfaces. When some data is updated on the server, a message is typically sent over a WebSocket connection to be handled by the client. WebSockets provide a more efficient alternative to continually polling your application's server for data changes that should be reflected in your UI.

> The core concepts behind broadcasting are simple: clients connect to named channels on the frontend, while your Laravel application broadcasts events to these channels on the backend. These events can contain any additional data you wish to make available to the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way how communication with web applications works in this case Laravel app is by using HTTP protocol. We send a request to the server and we get back a response from it. When the response is built from the server of course it has the most updated state, but these data can change after we receive the response. The only way to receive these data or the most updated state is by making another HTTP request to the server.
To make a new request we may refresh the page or click a link etc. Well, this is not always convenient because sometimes as in your case, you may want real-time data or at least close to real-time data. So to achieve this you may want to automate this process and create an interval to make HTTP requests to the server to get the most updated state.
One way could be to set an interval to refresh the page every ten seconds but that's not a good solution since on the page could be other content that you don't want to update so often(e.x. posts) but only the notifications.
To get the most updated state of some part of your page in this case notifications you must use ajax. Let me show you a simple example with posts count that will update the posts count every 10 seconds. It's a simple example but you'll understand the point here:

1)Create a migration file to create the posts table on the database. Here I'm showing only the up function.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('body');
    });
}
```

2)Create a post/index.blade.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Posts Count</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="posts-count"></div>

    <script>
        // Define a function to get the posts count using fetch API
        function getPostsCount() {
            fetch('/posts/count')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    // Update the posts count in the HTML
                    document.getElementById('posts-count').textContent = data.count;
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        }

        // Call the function to get the initial posts count
        getPostsCount();

        // Call the function every 10 seconds using setInterval
        setInterval(getPostsCount, 10000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

3)In the web.php file add the following routes:

```
Route::get('/posts', function(){
  return view('post.index');
})->name('post.index');

Route::get('/posts/count', function () {
    $count = Post::count();
    return response()->json(['count' => $count]);
});
```

After you reach the /posts endpoint you will see 0 displayed. But if you add a new post and wait for 10 seconds you will see that the 0 will become 1. And that will happen without any of your interaction.

I didn't take care of how to create post feature assuming you can use php artisan tinker. Also didn't mention commands such as php artisan serve, php artisan migrate and any other one if I forgot to mention. At the end I would say that instead of `then` you could use `async` `await`. But this is just a dummy example and all I wanted is to show here is the functionality.

Comment: i used ajax and javascript notification library instead of laravel's and it works! thanks for your explanation tho, it'll be very useful in the future when i need real-time notification :D